# How to create google reCAPTCHA v2.0 validation using jQuery Validation Plugin and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, recaptcha

I want to create validation for recaptcha filed using jQuery Validation Plugin and also php with Session.

## jQuery

I am useing (https://jqueryvalidation.org/) this jquery plugin for form validation and i do it. but i want to create validation for recaptcha filed using this plugin, but i can't create it.
[Here is a validation](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/06/03/adding-recaptcha-validator-to-jquery-validate/) for google recaptcha v1.0 using these plugin.
Please help me to create validation for google recaptcha v2.0 (filed) using this pulgin.

## PHP

I am also want to create validation use $_SESSION and i am try to create it, in my (signup-process.php) page and i print the session message in my form page under the recaptcha filed. it's not working :(

======
 Please help me to create validation for recaptcha filed using this both way.

## HTML

```
<form action="signup-process.php" method="post" id="signupForm">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-key"></div>

 <!--Session validation message-->
  /*<?php if(isset($_SESSION["ReC"]) && !empty($_SESSION["ReC"])){
      echo $_SESSION["ReC"];
       unset($_SESSION["ReC"]); }?> */

     <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="submitted">
  </form>
```

## JS

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your name",
        }
    });
```

## signup-process.php

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])&& !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){

    $secret = "my-key";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $rsp  = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip$ip");

    $arr = json_decode($rsp,TRUE);
    if($arr['success'] == "true"){
        echo 'Done';
    }else{
        echo 'SPam';
} else {
    $_SESSION["ReC"]="Please select captcha";
        header("location:signup.php");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New reCaptcha with jQuery Validation Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563822/new-recaptcha-with-jquery-validation-plugin)

Comment: @Vishnu Bhadoriya, It's not working as i want.
[recaptcha 2 validation](http://formvalidation.io/addons/recaptcha2/#example) I want like this validation plugin work but this is a premium plugin.

Comment: Hello @Vishnu Bhadoriya,
Thanks so so much it's working now.
but i couldn't understand why it's not work before.

Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NK If you apply your php validation message On top of the form tag. it will works.

## like this

```
 <!--Session validation message-->
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION["ReC"]) && !empty($_SESSION["ReC"])){
    echo $_SESSION["ReC"];
    unset($_SESSION["ReC"]); }
?>

<form action="signup-process.php" method="post" id="signupForm">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-key"></div>
  <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="submitted">
</form>
```

Comment: For this issues i can't continue my work.
It's work now properly :) 
Thank you so much @MD Iyasin Arafat