# reCaptcha v2 in conjunction with jQuery-Form-Validator

Tags: html, forms, recaptcha, jquery-form-validator

I'm using the [jQuery-Form-Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net). Now I want to integrate reCaptcha v2 into my form. The conjunction between both reCaptcha and the validator is somewhat unclear and hardly explained on the [official website](http://www.formvalidator.net/#security-validators_recaptcha) of the validator. I'm not searching a general solution to incorporate reCaptcha into a form because I know what to do. But I want to know how to do it with the above mentioned validator. Google wants you to paste

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
```

The validator simply suggests to paste

```
<input data-validation="recaptcha" data-validation-recaptcha-sitekey="[RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY]">
```

But what now? It is not explained how the reCaptcha has to be implemented into the validator. I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form role="form" method="post" action="php/formHandler.php">
        <div class="form-group">                                    
            <input id="name" name="name" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="2-40" data-sanitize="trim escape" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">                                    
            <input data-validation="email" data-sanitize="trim escape" type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">                                    
            <textarea data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min1" data-sanitize="trim escape" class="form-control input-lg" id="message" name="message"  placeholder="message" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha form-group" data-sitekey="my_sitekey">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
            send
        </button>                               
    </form>         
   <script src="lib/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>                                             
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

I've seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563822/new-recaptcha-with-jquery-validation-plugin), but it doesn't answer my question. I want to understand how to use

```
<input data-validation="recaptcha" data-validation-recaptcha-sitekey="[RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY]">
```

to make the reCaptcha working with the form. If there is anybody who uses that validator and has successfully implemented reCaptcha v2 I will be happy to hear about it...