# reCAPTCHA and Dropzone JS

Tags: recaptcha, dropzone.js

[image: reCAPTCHA]

Is it possible to combine [Google's incredible reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha) and Matias Meno's incredible [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), to prevent attacks and deter spam bots?

Answer (score 0):

Using wordpress.
This is what I came up with following a few tutorials:

- [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902539/how-can-i-validate-google-recaptcha-v2-using-javascript-jquery)
- [codeforgeek](http://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/google-recaptcha-tutorial/)
- And some others I dont remember

  ```
  // Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; //I use Autodiscover
  Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

  // The configuration we've talked about above
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 100,
  maxFiles: 100,
  previewsContainer: '.fileupload',

  // The setting up of the dropzone
  init: function() {
      var myDropzone = this;

      // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
      this.element.querySelector("input[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          // myDropzone.processQueue();

          var valid = true;
          $('[data-required]').each(function(i,ele){
              if(ele.value == ''){
                  $(this).parent().parent().addClass('alert');
                  valid = false;
              }
          });
          if (!valid){
              e.preventDefault();
              scrollTop();
              return false;
          }

          // Get the recaptcha input
          var cap_input = grecaptcha.getResponse();
          $.ajax({
              url: homeUrl+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "JSON",
              data: {
                  "action": "verifyReCaptcha",
                  "g-recaptcha-response": cap_input
              },
              success: function(response){
                  console.log(response);

                  if(response == 'Good captcha'){


                      if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
                          myDropzone.processQueue();
                      }
                      else {
                          // Upload anyway without files
                          if (wantToUpload == 'unknown') {
                              $('#noFiles').modal();
                              e.preventDefault();
                              return false;
                          }
                          else if (wantToUpload == false) {
                              myDropzone.uploadFiles([ ]);
                          }
                          else {
                              myDropzone.uploadFiles([ ]);
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  else{
                      console.log('Spammer go away');
                      $('.g-recaptcha').addClass('alert');
                  }
              }
          });
      });

      // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
      // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
      this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
      // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
      // Hide the success button or the complete form.
      console.log('sending');
  });
      this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
      // Redirect user or notify of success.
      console.log('success');
  });
      this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
      // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
      console.log('error');
  });
  }
  }
  ```

And some html/php

```
<form name="" action="<?=get_permalink();?>" method="post" id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="label" for="text-435">
        <?=__('Name*','gt_domain');?>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="client-name" value="" size="40" class="input__field--manami" id="text-435" data-required="true">

    <!-- Lots of input fields -->

    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 fileupload dropzone-previews dz-message">
        <h2 class="text-center" id="fileuploadtext">
            <?=__('Click or drag and drop your file here <br>(Max 60mb)','gt_domain');?>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_PUBLIC_KEY"></div>
    <input class="dangerzone-submit" type="submit" value="<?=__('Request quote','gt_domain');?>" name="dangerzone-submit">
</form>
```

And for ajax validation before submitting the form:

```
function verifyReCaptcha(){
        $email;
        $comment;
        $captcha = false;
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo json_encode('Please check the the captcha form.');
          exit;
        }
        $response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=MY_SUPER_SECRET_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);
        if($response['success'] == false){
          echo json_encode('You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out');
        }
        else{
          echo json_encode('Good captcha');
        }
        exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_verifyReCaptcha', 'verifyReCaptcha' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_verifyReCaptcha', 'verifyReCaptcha' );
```

And finnaly recieve form inputs and images:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['dangerzone-submit'])) {
    // print_r($_POST);
    $client = $_POST['client-name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];



    if ($_FILES) {
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            // print_r($array);
            if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK &&  $_FILES[$file]['error'][0] !== 0) {
                echo "upload error : \n";
                print_r($_FILES[$file]['error']);
                print_r($_FILES);
                die();
            }
            $uploads_dir = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/dropzone/';
            $external_link = get_home_url().'/wp-content/uploads/dropzone/';

            foreach ($array['name'] as $key => $val) {
                print_r($key);
                $name = $array['name'][$key];
                $tmp_name = $array['tmp_name'][$key];
                $newfilename = wp_unique_filename( $uploads_dir, $name );

                $movefile = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$newfilename);
                $uploaded_files[] = $external_link.$newfilename;
            }
        }
    }


    sendMail( //My func for sending mail
            $client,
            $email,
            $company,
            $phone,
            $comments,
            $uploaded_files
        );

}
?>
```

Comment: Client side "verifyReCaptcha" is a very bad pattern, the only way to secure api call is a backend/server side validation of token from Google. Anyone can call your endpoint by bypassing  validation.

Comment: Oh, just saw this. An old answer, and I don't remember what I was doing back then, but I'm pretty sure the validation is done in the backend, in my answer at least.

Comment: When I look at it now, it kinda looks like Typescript, but it's definitely php.

Comment: Sorry it's my bad, you are right, PHP it's not client side, I don't understand my own comment...