# ReCaptcha v2 client side events

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Does [ReCaptcha v2](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) expose any client side events? I am looking specifically to identify when the Captcha response has been returned once the box is ticked, so I can reveal the "Continue" button below.

[image]

Without this it is possible for the user to click the checkbox then quickly click the submit button before the captcha response is back.

I could possible add my own click event handler to the class `recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark` and poll the visiblity of the tick, I just wondered if there was a simpler way to do this?

```
$(".recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark").click(function() {
    //...Poll for visibility of tick
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I validate google reCAPTCHA v2 using javascript/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902539/how-can-i-validate-google-recaptcha-v2-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Not quite the same as here the question is how to validate on submit. I am trying to control the submit button visibility.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can configure reCAPTCHA to give a callback on successful validation using the data-callback attribute on the g-recaptcha tag or via the 'callback' parameter if using explicit rendering.

See
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param

Example using explicit rendering:

```
var myCallback = function(val) { console.log(val); };
grecaptcha.render(
   document.getElementsById('my-recaptcha-placeholder'), 
   {
     callback: myCallback, 
     sitekey: mySiteKey
   });
```

Answer (score 48):

Another solution is to set `data-callback` directly on the `g-recaptcha` div, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var imNotARobot = function() {
    console.info("Button was clicked");
  };
</script>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="imNotARobot" data-sitekey="key"></div>
```

Comment: Additionally, if you're displaying a "Continue" button on validation, you might also want to hide it when your validation expires with the `data-expired-callback` attribute, since recaptcha validation does expire after a few seconds of inactivity.

Comment: Finally, someone actually gave an answer that worked! Thank you! I tried so many before I got one. It's good to know you can trigger a callback right from the placeholder.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.