# Google ReCAPTCHA setting v2

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a [form](http://sergiykravchuk.com/contacts.html) with `google reCaptcha v2`. But in my code when person didn't check the icon `I'm not a robot`, the code sends the person to a new page with the message `Please check the the captcha form`.

I need when person doesn't check the icon `I'm not a robot`, he/she stays on the same page with the message: `Please check the the captcha form`. Here is an [example](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) of what I want

I have a contact form (name, telephone and text message)

```
<?php
    $email;$comment;$captcha;
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
      $email=$_POST['email'];
    }if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
      $email=$_POST['comment'];
    }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
      exit;
    }
    $secretKey = "************";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
    if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
      echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
    } else {
      echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
    }
```

Can you help me with it?

Comment: Be careful, you let your private key. 
You have to generate a new to avoid hacking.

Comment: thanks I forget about it

Comment: @SergiyK. You will need to generate a new key, edits are stored in questions are visible on SO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902539/how-can-i-validate-google-recaptcha-v2-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use #Javascript to validate that clients has been checked your captcha first. Then send the submit form i thef captcha is checked.

Comment: Can you help me with it. For me its to hard.