# Run an external function simultaneously with Jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, recaptcha

I have a form where I am using Jquery validate for client side validations. I have also used a google recaptcha in the form. The problem here is, I want to run client side validations on the reCaptcha div so that the user does not leave it unchecked. I have a function which validates the recaptcha but I am not able to run it simultaneously with the validate. I have to explicitly mention it in my `submitHandler` of the validate. Below is my code snippet:

```
$('#newform').validate({
        'rules': {
            'name': {
                required: true
            },
            'age': {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
        'messages': {
            'name': {
                required: 'Name is required'
            },
            'age': {
                required: 'Age is required',
                number: 'Age must be a number'
            }
        },
        'submitHandler': function(form) {
            recaptcha_validate(form); //This runs the validation on the reCaptcha
        }
    });

<form id="newform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"></input><br/>
        <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="age"></input><br/>
        <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="file"/><br/>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site-key"></div>
        <span id="captcha_error"/> <!-- Displays the error message for captcha -->
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send"></input>
</form>
```

**My question**: Is it possible to run the captcha validation function at the ***same time*** as the actual validation handlers run? Currently the captcha validation runs **after** all the fields are validated, since it is written in the `submitHandler`.
reCaptcha validation function courtesy [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902539/how-can-i-validate-google-recaptcha-v2-using-javascript-jquery) post.

Comment: Please show the actual code *you are using* rather than linking to another question.  You might be able to do it using a custom rule.  See `.addMethod()`.

Comment: Well @Sparky this is the actual code. The link to another question is just a reference to the function I'm using which is not really relevant to the problem here since it is working just fine. Also `.addMethod()` is less likely to work since reCaptcha is an external API. Anyways which I shall try to use it for sure.

Comment: Since you're asking how to integrate this functionality into jQuery Validate, of course it's relevant to show the code that is already working.  Regardless, if you want a rule that is part of the plugin and evaluated at the same time as the other rules, then `.addMethod()` is the way to attempt this.