# How to show reCAPTCHA before a page loads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How could I show reCAPTCHA before a page loads, like it shows the reCAPTCHA when a user visits the page and they need to fill out the reCAPTCHA then if they successfully filled out the reCAPTCHA it'd load the pages contents.

Comment: for that you will need 2 pages:1. for the recaptcha 2. the page with the content, you will need a way to test if the user is allowed to access the second page and redirect him to the recaptcha page if he hasn't solved it

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, you will need to add an extra step in between.

You can add a page that says something like

> Click here if you are a human

And then put your recaptcha validation in a button where the user responds

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you don't that. When a webpage load first execute your server side language then client side language. You add ajax system.

Comment: Could you help me with that then?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide/disable your page content untill user verify captcha process, also visit this for an idea,

[How can I validate google reCAPTCHA v2 using javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902539/how-can-i-validate-google-recaptcha-v2-using-javascript-jquery)