# RecaptchaV2 enable/disable submit

Tags: jquery, forms, recaptcha

I have a form in my web but I've been receiving some span so I add Google RecaptchaV2 and it stop the span but I would like disable the Submit button until the Recaptcha is checked and the user prove that is human.

The RecaptchaV2 run inside a Iframe, how can I read an element or a property to disable the Submit?

Inside the Iframe there is a span that change content once is verified:
from:

`<span id="recaptcha-accessible-status">Recaptcha requires verification</span>`

to:

```
<span id="recaptcha-accessible-status">You are verified</span>
```

So reading that I think might be possible disable/enable the submit button with Jquery, tried using content() to read it but can't access to the iframe content, any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: And what did you tried so far?

Comment: I included more details on the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I validate google reCAPTCHA v2 using javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902539/how-can-i-validate-google-recaptcha-v2-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Got it mate, thank you very much!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the answer, this is just to disable/enable the submit button on check:

Made it to work with different forms in one page but not tested, any suggestions/changes are welcome.

Call:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="KEY-HERE" data-callback="correctCaptcha"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en"></script>
```

The **data-callback="correctCaptcha"** is the master piece.

js:

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).find(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
function correctCaptcha() {
    $("form").each(function() {
        $(this).find(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
    });
}
```

Comment: great solution. and for vanilla JS I just gave my submit button an ID and used this line in the correctCaptcha function:  document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = false;

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
  var verifyCallback = function(response) {
    $('.contactForm :input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
  };

  var onloadCallback = function() {        
    grecaptcha.render('contactForm', {
      'sitekey' : 'SITE-KEY-HERE',
      'callback' : verifyCallback,
      'theme' : 'light'
    });
  };
```