# Using scripts in angular 6 - recaptcha

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, recaptcha

I am trying to implement recaptcha in my project, but I'm not sure how to use it.

I'm importing script in this way:

```
public loadScript() {
let body = <HTMLDivElement>document.body;
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = '';
script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
script.async = true;
script.defer = true;
body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Then I call this function in component constructor, and it works - recaptcha is properly rendered and works, but how to get response for my backend from it?

I tried `grecaptcha.getResponse()` but I get `ReferenceError: "grecaptcha is not defined"` - what is interesting not always. So how to make Typescript know what  grecaptcha is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I validate google reCAPTCHA v2 using javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902539/how-can-i-validate-google-recaptcha-v2-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Not really a solution to the problem, but wouldn't it be better to use a library like [ng-recaptcha](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha) to avoid hacking around in the DOM yourself to get recaptcha?

Answer (score 5):

> **To Use Google reCAPTCHA v3 in Angular 4,5,6 follow the simple steps**
>
> Register For the public key on [Google official Recaptcha website](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/)

Now Add following script file in your angular project **index.html**

```
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Then add the following tag in your **Component file** where you want to use Captcha

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="captcha_element" class="g-recaptcha" 
     [attr.data-sitekey]="siteKeyCaptcha"></div>
</div>
```

Now update your **Typescript file** with the following code.

```
declare var grecaptcha: any;

//declare Varible with public key given by Google
siteKeyCaptcha: string = "6LdF6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxWVT";

//when we route back from the page we have to render captcha again
grecaptcha.render('capcha_element', {
  'sitekey': this.siteKeyCaptcha
});
```

> To get a Response from Captcha on click add call back event as follows
>       in **HTML**

```
**HTML**
<div class="form-group">
   <div id="capcha_element" class="g-recaptcha" 
   data-callback="getResponceCapcha" [attr.data-sitekey]="siteKeyCaptcha"></div>
</div>

**Typescript**
ngOnInit() {
  //....rest of code....
  window['getResponceCapcha'] = this.getResponceCapcha.bind(this);
}

getResponceCapcha(captchaResponse: string) {
   this.verifyCaptcha(captchaResponse);
}

verifyCaptcha(captchaResponse: string) {
  //you can do HTTP call from here
}
```

> **Click [here](https://angular-mqhtvt.stackblitz.io) for example and [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqhtvt) for code**